# Regression graph in R or Python

Tags: python, r, regression

Is it possible to reproduce this Regression graph in R or Python?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

This graph was produced using the acQuire 4 QAQC object. [Link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/use-regression-lines-paired-data-scatter-plots-quality-paul-fell/)

And this is the model that I have created so far.

```
dados = read.csv("C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\data3.csv", header = T)

# 0. Build linear model 
model <- lm(CK ~ OR, data = dados)
summary(model)

# 1. Add predictions 
pred.int <- predict(model, interval = "prediction")
mydata <- cbind(dados, pred.int)


# 2. Regression line
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(OR, CK)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm)


# 3. Add prediction intervals
p + geom_line(aes(y = lwr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_line(aes(y = upr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

My database: [Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkUK-qGIRBnMgblFmmGPhK4v_LNanw?e=gXcYy2)

Comment: Hi Thiago, I think if you look at the data, it appears there is some independent variable that is influencing the distribution. Perhaps you should consider what that variable is and try to model it. Otherwise, your linear model is not going to predict your data very well.

Comment: In fact, I wanted to reproduce only the lines in the graph above: (X = Y), (10%) and (20%) in the graph below.

Comment: Please clarify how you propose to estimate `CK = OR` when there is clearly an influence of a latent categorical variable.